# Get YouTube URLs from a document using Regex in Dart/Flutter

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, url, youtube

I have seen some `StackOverflow` answers to this question but they all used `JavaScript`

The question is:- How to get YouTube URLs from a document using Regex in Dart/Flutter

I have a document that comes from my backend and has `HTML` tags and it has an embedded `YouTube` video in it. But in the end, it's just like a text document, isn't it?

First here is my document that I want to get the `YouTube` link from

```
    <figure
      class="wp-block-embed-youtube wp-block-embed is-type-video is-provider-youtube wp-embed-aspect-4-3 wp-has-aspect-ratio">
      <div class="wp-block-embed__wrapper">
        <iframe
          title="| Title here |"
          width="1170"
          height="878"
          src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OWGnQ61kLzw?feature=oembed" // <-- I want to get this link
          frameborder="0"
          allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
          allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
      </div>
    </figure>
```

Here is my `Dart` code that I use to get this but I fail

```
    String getYouTubeUrl(String content) {
      RegExp regExp = RegExp(
          r'^((?:https?:)?\/\/)?((?:www|m)\.)?((?:youtube\.com|youtu.be))(\/(?:[\w\-]+\?v=|embed\/|v\/)?)([\w\-]+)(\S+)?$');
      String matches = regExp.stringMatch(content);
      if (matches == null) {
        return ''; // Always returns here while the video URL is in the content paramter
      }
      final String youTubeUrl = matches;
      return youTubeUrl;
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is my `RegExp` correct? Here is what I want:- https://regexr.com/3dj5t

The `RegExp` is actually correct according to the mentioned website but in Dart I can't seem to get it to work

Now, how can I extract the YouTube URL from this document?

Comment: use https://pub.dev/packages/html

Comment: with that package you will be able to get not only src url but also `title` or `width` or `height` by simply calling `iframe['src']` / `iframe['title']` etc

Comment: @pskink Can you please explain how it works? And make an answer so that I might mark it too. I can't get it to work because it gives me an error iframe['src'] is not a valid selector...

Here is how I'm doing it

`` Document document = parse(content);
  print(document.querySelector('iframe["src"]')); ``

Comment: `var video = doc.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
((?:https?:)?\/\/)?((?:www|m)\.)?((?:youtube\.com|youtu.be))(\/(?:[\w\-]+\?v=|embed\/|v\/)?)([\w\-]+)(\S+)?
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/24KmKH/1)

[Dart Demo](https://ideone.com/jhlTUa)

**Explanation:**

in your document, the youtube link is not at the start of the line and not end exactly at the end of the line so ^ and $ is unnecessary